# Number of intersected features from one layer per feature from second layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geoprocessing, spatial-analysis

How can I get number of intersecting features from one layer per feature from second layer using any component from QGIS 2.8 (GRASS, SAGA, Python scripting...)? Result should be stored in new attribute column.

Comment: So you have one layer with a set of shapes, and for each of those shapes you want to know how many shapes from another layer intersect it? Simplest method is probably a spatial join/query - in Arc this would produce a join count field, not sure about QGIS. Failing that you could intersect the two layers and then use the groupstats plugin to summarize the result based on the id field from the layer you want to count against. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150177/ for recent Arc version of this question, if I'm understanding right.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. But I can't use ArcGIS.

Comment: QGIS does have a [spatial join](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html) but I'm not sure it gives you a count. To get around that you could add a field to your many polygons layer and give it a value of 1, then in the spatial join use the summary of intersecting features sum method on that field, which would give you such a count.

Answer (score 2):

A **Virtual Layer** can handle *aggregate* and *spatial join*.

```
SELECT polygon2.id AS POLYGON, Count(*) AS RESULT_COUNT
FROM polygon1 JOIN polygon2
ON st_intersects(polygon1.geometry, polygon2.geometry)=1
GROUP BY polygon2.id
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using QGIS 2.14.20, you can use Join attributes by location from `Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join attributes by location` and select the option `Take summary of intersecting features` and select `Sum` (it means `Count`)

[image]

Example of two polygons intersecting each other:

[image]

The output Join attributes by location with Sum option selected creates a new column `Count`:

[image]