# How to count number of polygon within each 2nd poylgon layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

So I need to count the number of parcels (first polygon layer) that lie with in each unit boundary (2nd polygon layer). PS There are over 300 Unit boundaries in which I need to find out the number of of parcels in each.

Comment: I would first do a spatial join, joining the unit boundary to the parcels layer, then run the summary statistics tool on the output. The statistics tool will allow you to count the number of parcels for every unique unit boundary ID

Comment: Are the parcels coincident with the unit boundaries? If not, what should happen when a parcel falls within two different unit boundaries - counted only toward one or both? @Dowlers the spatial join already does a count for you, no need to summarize if you do the join right. Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150177/ (points and polygons would be treated largely the same here).

Comment: You can try the [Tabulate Intersection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/tabulate-intersection.htm) tool if you have an Advanced license. You might need to make a dummy field and Field Calculate "1" in every row. Then sum the "1"s for the "_sum_fields_" argument.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you'll want to do is convert your parcel features to points. [Feature To Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003m000000) tool to do so, and make sure you pick `Inside` for your point location. This will alleviate and boundary issues you may have.

After converting your parcels to points you can perform a spatial join. Add your unit boundary feature class and your parcel point feature class to ArcMap's table of contents. Right-click on the unit boundary layer in the table of contents and choose `Joins and Relates` -> `Join...`.

A new window opens. For your layer to join, choose your parcel point layer. Use defaults for the rest of the options should be fine. Run your join.

[image]

Your newly created feature class will have the field `Count_`, with the count of parcel points within each boundary.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe converting to points is necessary, and at best it's misleading to state that will 'alleviate any boundary issues' when you don't know the business rules for those conflicts if they even exist. It's also worth pointing out that Feature to Point requires an Advanced license to use.

Comment: @Chris W good point about my assumptions.