# Counting point objects near each feature in polyline layer of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, spatial-statistics

I am having a little trouble finding a strategy for this. I have a polyline layer with Fiber segments, each have a FiberID. They are not unique, sometimes there will be two segments with the same fiberID.

I also have another point layer that contains the Splice Points. I was wondering if there was a strategy that I could get a count of the Splice points that were within a certain distance, lets say 50 feet of each record in the Fiber Polyline layer. So the result I'd be looking for is a table that shows the number of splices (points) within 50 feet of each record in the polyline table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible ways to do this with a variety of tools depending on your license level. You might look at the Generate Near Table tool if you have access to it (Advanced level only). It can also be done with a Spatial Join at the Basic level. Adapting my answer from [Spatial Join - One Join Feature to Multiple Target Features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150177/), you would use the following settings:

Target Features fiber segments and Join Features splice points, give a name for the results feature class, leave Join Operation set to join_one_to_one, leave the Keep box checked, ignore the Field Map section, change the Match Option to Within_A_Distance and then set a 50 foot search radius (be sure to specify foot units in the drop-down to the side).

The resulting table will have a column called Join Count, which tells you the number of points that were joined to each segment. It does not matter how many segments a point falls within 50 feet of, it will be counted once for each.

Comment: The Generate Near Table worked for what I needed. I just used the Splice ID. I just used a 50 foot search radius with the splices as the near feature. Then did Summary Statistics with the IN_FID and "COUNT" statistic type and IN_FID case field.

Answer (score 1):

You can buffer your polylines, dissolve type None, to whichever distance you would need. Then intersect the buffers and Splice Points. The results will have the FiberID, and the Splice Points